# Calibration of camera using ROS, without camera info

Tags: ros, robotic-arm, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

As part of a college project, I need to communicate with a TM5-700 robotic arm developed by Omron, and implement, for now, a pick and place pipeline. For that, I am required to access the camera information. For now, my plan is to use aruco stickers for the image detection however I am running into an issue. The packages require the camera to be calibrated, at least as far as I understand, and the image pipeline package of ROS, is asking for a camera info service from the camera driver. I can provide the raw_image from the camera, however it is not possible to provide any camera information. The communication package is from the following github link: https://github.com/TechmanRobotInc/tmr_ros1/. Any help would be appreciated. I am also quite new with ROS and camera vision, so apologies if i do not specify enough information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you are missing the camera_info.

Here is a way to create the camera_info topic:

You definitely need to calibrate your camera. Here is the [documenation](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration)  for this package and also a [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration).

With this you will create a .yaml file representing the camera info and save it somewhere.

From there you can either publish the camera_info topic yourself, [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/248563/publishing-camerainfo-messages-from-yaml-file/) are a few ideas for that.
Or you could use [ROS OpenCV](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_camera) camera driver which takes the device_id of you camera in linux and your created yaml file and publishes image_raw and corresponding camera_info topic.